# Words not staying in css toggle

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, slidetoggle

I have a toggle that I am using for twitter bootstrap, and one of the words is poping out and not staying inside the toggle, I highlighted the messed up word in a red box below:

[image]

My code is:

```
<div class=\"span9 space\">
                        <h3 class=\"title pull-left\">$name</h3> 

                        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"lib/prism/prism-light.css\">
                        <script src=\"lib/prism/prism.js\"></script>

                        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"toggle-switch.css\">


                        <form class=\"form-horizontal pull-right\">
                            <div class=\"control-group\">
                                <label class=\"control-label\"></label>
                                <div class=\"controls btn disabled switch switch-two\">
                                    <input id=\"week9\" name=\"view\" type=\"radio\" checked>
                                    <label for=\"week9\" onclick=\"\">Not Visited</label>

                                    <input id=\"month10\" name=\"view\" type=\"radio\"> 
                                    <label for=\"month10\" onclick=\"\">Visited</label>



                                    <span class=\"slide-button btn btn-warning\"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>


                    </div>
```

The toggle I am using is from here:

http://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switch/bootstrap.html

Here is also my live code:

http://www.beerportfolio.com/breweryPage2.php?id=BSsTGw

Comment: Is it because the CSS has a width and can't fit 'not visited' all in that small space and it is moving it down?

Comment: do you really have all these backslashes in your html?

Comment: I am outputting with php and needed to escape them @didierc

Comment: @Mike Theoretically, if they're outside any `<?php` `?>` tags, you don't have to escape the double-quotes. Plus, if they were inside, you could use single quotes and save you the extra keystrokes ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the Switch class does not stretch for your words,

you can solve it by hardcoding the width in the switch class in your style sheet or by adding it in the div you want stretch and this should solve your issue

```
<div class=\"controls btn disabled switch switch-two\" style=\"width: xxxpx !important;\">
```

while xxx represent the value you need

Comment: Kind of works, but makes it un-toggleable click works once then doesn't work. And the whole thing moves down a bit when there is still plenty of room for it. 

See the link in  my post to see the progress

Comment: I spend 70% of my programming time, searching for missing comma :) you welcome

Answer (score 0):

I did a live edit on the demo you supplied and used your values for the items and added a smaller width than what is needed and the visited part of 'Not Visited' went to a new line. You might want to have a larger width for your toggle item(s).

**EDIT:**
It looks like you did modify some of the css or it inherited some, you can modify it any way you want but try:
toggle-switch line 210

```
.toggle label,
.toggle p,
.switch label {
    line-height: 13px;/*30px*/
}
```

and remove:
bootstrap.min.css line 333

```
.form-horizontal .controls {
    margin-left: 0;/*180px*/
}
```

Comment: But if you look on the link I supplied: http://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switch/bootstrap.html

those examples are huge...

Comment: @Mike yes they are. Did you modify some css to have a smaller width?

Comment: Nope. I just added a link to my live code, if it helps you check it out.